# Dynamic SQL Query returns column name instead of value

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I am trying to create some queries passing the column name dynamically, but for some reason is returning the Column name and not the value.
I am not very familiar with this technique, for now @cmd is empty because before I write the dynamic query I wanted to make sure I will pass the correct parameters. In other words, I want to print the value that is in the column A1.

Can anyone please tell or guide me to get the value instead? I will appreciate any help.

HubFinal

```
  id    Cart      PO              A1               A1E  
  ----------------------------------------------------------
  01    Cart1     24432     upc1,1/25/2016,1      Available
  -----------------------------------------------------------
  02    Cart2     24888     upc10,1/25/2030,1     No Available
```

Query

```
WHILE (@i <= 1)
BEGIN

--  get Column Name Example A1
    SET @Compartment = (SELECT compartment FROM @Compartment_table WHERE idx = @i);

--  get data from HUBFINAL to insert into HUBTEMP
    SET @PO = (Select PO FROM HubFinal Where CartPlate =@CartPlate);

--  pass dynamically the comlumn name, in this case A1
    SET @CompValue = (Select  @Compartment From HubFinal Where  CartPlate =@CartPlate);


Print @Compartment 
Print @PO
Print @CompValue 



--insert to final table
         Declare @cmd nvarchar(4000) =
              -- do something with values gotten above
         EXEC(@cmd)


-- increment counter for next compartment
    SET @i = @i + 1

END
```

Output

```
-- this is what is printed

  A1
  24432
  A1
```

Comment: How could we possible help without knowing your actual dynamic SQL query?. Anyway, try printing `@cmd`, you should see there why you get the results that you are getting

Comment: Hi Lamak, I am not very familiar with this technique,  for now  @cmd is empty because before I write the dynamic query I wanted to make sure I will pass the correct parameters. In other words, I want to print the value that is in the column A1.

Comment: The problem is the way you are trying to use variables. In your third query you are selecting the column name that was a result of the first query. To accomplish what you are trying to do would require dynamic sql. You can't use a variable to define which column to select like that.

Comment: Even once you figure out the dynamic sql portion this process seems to be in a loop. Looping is horrible for performance in sql server and shouldn't be used to select values like you are doing here. The whole process you are putting together seems to need a massive rethinking.

Comment: Sean, thank you for your advice! I was thinking to do it this way because this function will be use once in a while so performance for this specific function is not a priority but I really appreciate all the info you provided me.

Comment: Even only things used no and then deserve to perform reasonably well. I get what you mean about it not being a high priority but removing the looping here is probably pretty simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @Sean Lange told you ... It's not recommended to loop in sql server as it will hit the performance (you should find another way to solve you problem), but if you want to get the value of a dynamic column name you can do it like that

as I don't know the data type you are working with I assuming that it's NVARCHAR

```
DECLARE @value NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @CompValue = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), 'Select  @val='+ @Compartment + ' From HubFinal Where CartPlate = @CartPlate')

EXECUTE sp_executesql @CompValue, N'@CartPlate NVARCHAR(MAX),@val NVARCHAR OUTPUT', @CartPlate = @CartPlate, @val= @value OUTPUT

PRINT(@value)
```

Comment: Hi Sherif Ahmed, thank you for your response!  I tried your solution and is printing this `Select  A1 From HubFinal Where CartPlate = cart1` for @CompValue

Comment: Thank you so much!  `sp_executesql` made it.